# Some comments have a way of disappearing: who can delete a comment, apart from their author?

Tags: discussion, support, comments

Who can delete a comment, apart from their author?
Because it seems to me certain comments have a way of disappearing… ?!

Comment: The only people who can delete other users' comments are moderators and community managers (CMs). You can identify them by the little diamond symbol in their username. And don't get too hung up on deleted comments: comments are ephemeral by design. And a big part of a mod's job is to clean up (i.e. obliterate) comments which have outlived their usefulness. (And, for the sake of completeness: SE sites are mostly self-moderating, so mods only step in when users can't or don't, and CMs [who are SE employees] only step in when mods can't or don't. In practice, comments are mostly deleted by mods.)

Comment: @DanBron Shouldn't that be entered as an answer?

Comment: @DanBron: also flags.

Comment: @sumelic Oh yeah, forgot about flags.